# how to add keyboard event to change parameters?

Tags: python, keyboard

i have some code to calculate radiation doses by formula.
The problem is - i want to add keyboard event to break loop while True and return to #DTU_01(start) write new parameters and then continue to calculate, but when i add keyboard, nothing happens but write in input field. There is a code on Python:

```
import json
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import keyboard
import time

init()

with open("DTU.json", 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print('Расчет дозы для трех установов ДТУ')
a1_values = [float(data[dtu]['a1']) for dtu in data]
b1_values = [float(data[dtu]['b1']) for dtu in data]
a2_values = [float(data[dtu]['a2']) for dtu in data]
a3_values = [float(data[dtu]['a3']) for dtu in data]
b2_values = [float(data[dtu]['b2']) for dtu in data]
b3_values = [float(data[dtu]['b3']) for dtu in data]

print('DTU-01_1:')
print('a1=', a1_values[0], 'b1=', b1_values[0], 'a2=', a2_values[0], 'b2=', b2_values[0], 'a3=', a3_values[0], 'b3=', b3_values[0])
print('DTU-01_2:')
print('a1=', a1_values[1], 'b1=', b1_values[1], 'a2=', a2_values[1], 'b2=', b2_values[1], 'a3=', a3_values[1], 'b3=', b3_values[1])
print('DTU-01_3:')
print('a1=', a1_values[2], 'b1=', b1_values[2], 'a2=', a2_values[2], 'b2=', b2_values[2], 'a3=', a3_values[2], 'b3=', b3_values[2])
k_sens1 = [1.5, 1.2245, 1, 0.8163, 0.6666, 0.5442, 0.4444]
k_sens2 = [1.4964, 1.2239, 1, 0.8167, 0.6678, 0.5459, 0.4461]
k_sens3 = [1.4948, 1.2236, 1, 0.8169, 0.6682, 0.54665, 0.4471]

# DTU-1(start)
dtu = int(input("Номер ДТУ = "))

if dtu == 1:
    a_m = [float(a1_values[0]), float(a2_values[0]), float(a3_values[0])]
    b_m = [float(b1_values[0]), float(b2_values[0]), float(b3_values[0])]
    b = b_m[0]
    a = a_m[0]
    k = k_sens1
elif dtu == 2:
    a_m = [float(a1_values[1]), float(a2_values[1]), float(a3_values[1])]
    a = a_m[0]
    b_m = [float(b1_values[1]), float(b2_values[1]), float(b3_values[1])]
    b = b_m[0]
    k = k_sens2
else:
    a_m = [float(a1_values[2]), float(a2_values[2]), float(a3_values[2])]
    a = a_m[0]
    b_m = [float(b1_values[2]), float(b2_values[2]), float(b3_values[2])]
    b = b_m[0]
    k = k_sens3
# DTU-1(end)

# KdrDf(start)
n = int(input("K_group = "))
ks = k[n]  # Correct index for ks
k_dr = float(input('K_dreif = '))
dfon = float(input("Dfon = "))
# KdrDf(end)

while True:
i1_str = input("I1 = ")
i2_str = input("I2 = ")

if ',' in i1_str:
    i1_str = i1_str.replace(',', '.')
if ',' in i2_str:
    i2_str = i2_str.replace(',', '.')

i_1 = float(i1_str)
i_2 = float(i2_str)

i1 = i_1 * ks
i2 = i_2 * ks
d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) - dfon

if 1.5 <= D < 15:
   a = a_m[1]
   b = b_m[1]
   d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
   d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
   D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) - dfon
   print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
elif D >= 15:
    a = a_m[2]
    b = b_m[2]
    d1 = (k_dr * i1 * a) + b
    d2 = (k_dr * i2 * a) + b
    D = ((d1 + d2) / 2) - dfon
    print(f"{Fore.RED}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
else:
    print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{round(D, 3)}{Style.RESET_ALL}")`
```

So, how can I add key event to break loop and return to the #DTU_01(start)?

Comment: 1) Your indentation is broken for the `while True:` loop - please edit your code and correct it; 2) If you want to return to a previous statement use another loop; 3) Adding `keyboard` isn't going to do anything if you don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple way to get there without changing your code much:

```py
# prelude

while True:
    # KdrDf(start)
    n = input("K_group = ")
    if n.lower() == "quit":
        break]
    n = int(n)
    ks = k[n]  # Correct index for ks
    # ...

    while True:
        i1_str = input("I1 = ")
        if i1_str.lower() == "reset":
            break
        i2_str = input("I2 = ")
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It worked as I wanted it to be.